# Cross platform launch records with extra data on Windows Phone and Android

Tags: android, windows-phone, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

Is it possible to create a cross platform NDEF Message to start an application on Android **and** Windows Phone passing additional data to the app?

What I am trying to do:

I have an application installed on Android and Windows Phone. It should be possible to start the applications with an NFC tag and I need to pass additional data from the tag (any string) to my applications.

To start the applications with the NFC tags, I created a Windows Phone LaunchApp Record and an Android Application Record (AAR) and store them on the tag.

Windows Phone needs the LaunchApp Record to be the first NDEF Record in the NDEF message. So the sequence of the NDEF message is:

1. Windows Phone LaunchApp Record
2. Android Application Record

To pass additional data, I can put some arguments in the Windows Phone LaunchApp Record, so that works fine. But it is not possible to put some additional data to the Android Application Record.

I tried to add a third NDEF Record to the message which contains the extra data for Android. I created an external record and I added the filter to my manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
        android:host="ext"
        android:pathPrefix="/myapp.com:customtype"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The problem is the sequence of the the NDEF message:

The Windows Phone record must be the first record in the message, but the additional record must also be the first record to receive the intent on Android.

**NDEF Message:**

1. External and LaunchApp Record
2. Android Application Record

If I have following record sequence I receive the extra data on Android and the application starts but then I can't open the application on Windows Phone because the record is the second one.

1. External Record
2. Windows Phone LaunchApp
3. Android Application Record

Is there any solution to this problem? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the following:

- Windows requires the LaunchApp record to be the first record of the NDEF message on the tag.
- Android will only pass the discovered NDEF message/NFC tag object to the app if the app has an intent filter for the first record of the NDEF message.
- The LaunchApp record is not a valid NDEF record (as its type name format indicates an absolute URI record but its type ("windows.com/LaunchApp") is **not** a valid absolute URI).

As a consequence, you cannot easily match that record (the LaunchApp record) with an intent filter on Android (URI intent filters match in the order scheme -> host -> path, but as there is no scheme, you cannot match for host/path).

The trick is to use an intent filter that matches any URI with an empty scheme:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="" />
</intent-filter>
```

Now if your NDEF message is

```
LaunchApp record | [optional other records] | Android Application record
```

your Android app will be invoked and the NDEF message/tag object will be passed in an `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent to the activity with the above intent filter.

Unfortunately, that intent filter will also be triggered for any other tag that contains a relative URI/any URI without a scheme and that does not contain an AAR for another app.

---

**UPDATE**

Code for creating my test LaunchApp record tag:

```
final Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);

if (ndefTag != null) {
    try {
        ndefTag.connect();
        ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
                    new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_ABSOLUTE_URI,
                                   "windows.com/LaunchApp".getBytes("US-ASCII"),
                                   null,
                                   "la:uz".getBytes("US-ASCII")),
                    NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord("at.mroland.launchrecordtest")
        }));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            ndefTag.close();
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest for the receiving app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="at.mroland.launchrecordtest"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".LaunchRecordTest"
                  android:label="LaunchRecordTest">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In `onCreate()`, I used `getIntent()` to retrieve the intent.

Comment: Thank you **Michael Roland** for this information. This means that the android application will be opened for every tag with any URI without a scheme?

Comment: Correct. (Though except for other tags with LaunchApp records, such tags should be rather rare.)

Comment: One question again. I tried to implement your suggestion with the empty schema intent filter. I never get the intent with the ndef message. The methods onNewIntent or in onCreate won't get the records.

Comment: Just tested (Android 4.4.4) and works when activity is started by the tag. Receiving the intent in onNewIntent() when your activity is already running is a different story though.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Could you share the code or maybe the records? I wrote a 1) LaunchApp Record , 2) optional Record and 3) the AAR but i am bot able to receive the NDEF discovered intent in onCreate().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83285/discussion-between-user2048767-and-michael-roland).

Comment: @MichaelRoland - any chance you could post up the final solution or point me to any blog posts please? I'm having exactly the same problem as described above. I have the token written, I have the WP working, but on android, it will only launch the app, and I don't receive the NDEF record. I know its there as I have a separate code to read the whole tag.

Comment: @SteveGoodman I'm not sure what you mean with "final solution". Everything's described in my answer above. This is tested to work at least on Android 4.4.4, unless you use Xamarin annotations(are these called annotations?) to create the intent filters.

Comment: @MichaelRoland thanks for the very quick response, it was just user2048767 continued the discussion in chat - however you may have part answered my question. Is there a problem using Xamarin annotations?

I have:
<code>[Activity(Label = "NFCFormsSample", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]

[IntentFilter(new[] { NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered },
Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault },
DataScheme = "")]

[MetaData(NfcAdapter.ActionNdefDiscovered, Resource = "@xml/nfc")]</code>

Comment: @SteveGoodman I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with them or if the problem that we discovered back then still exists (but I assume so). Back then the problem was simply that an empty scheme could not be modeled with the Xamarin annotation (i.e. DataScheme = "" does not create the correct intent filter).

Comment: @MichaelRoland - Thank you. the problem, still exists you need to edit the Properties\AndroidManifest.xml. You can see the output in the obj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml.

All working now.