# Launch a Windows Phone app with android AAR (NFC)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, nfc, ndef, windows-10-mobile, android-applicationrecord

I have a device with a hard-coded NFC tag that opens an Android app based on an Android Application Record (AAR). Basically it calls an Android app to open with type android.com:pkg and payload com.something.Something.

I have researched on how to launch my Windows Phone app with that existing tag, but in the end I have only found that Windows Phone can launch an app if the NFC tag is adequately programmed to open the Windows Phone app ID or the custom protocol registered in my app. But it is very important that I use the existing NFC tag which opens the Android app ID.

What is curious is that my Windows 10 Mobile detects this existing NFC tag to want to open the app when I touch it with my phone and prompts me if I want to launch an app? But the app with that ID isn't installed so I did a research on how to put this app ID on my Windows Phone app but in the end I only got deployment errors.

Answer (score 0):

Android Application Records (AAR) cannot be used to launch Windows apps. Windows uses a different system to launch apps (Launch Record). The main probem is that Windows uses a different scheme to identify apps (not a Java package name as Android does). Moreover, Windows apps cannot be set to be automatically launched based on the data contained in an AAR, hence, it's not possible to build some custom filter that starts your Windows app based on that AAR.

The workaround that's currently known seems to be what's discussed in [Cross platform launch records with extra data on Windows Phone and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31366156/2425802). Though this requires modification of the data structures on the tag side.

Comment: Thanks! But is it a bug then, that my W10M ask to launch the app when tapped on this tag? If this is not supposed to work ever then why does that prompt pop-up?

Comment: @JerkoCilas So does it ask you to open *your* app or does it ask you to open just any app?

Comment: W10M says that the tag wants to "open an app". Do I want to allow it? It does not say which app, and when I allow it nothing happens.

Comment: @JerkoCilas So this essentially just says "hey, I discovered a tag, do you want to do anything with it?". I would not expect this to be related to the AAR specifically.